# Razor Pages, how do i add route value to navigation link?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have tried injecting my Employee Model into _ViewImports.cshtml and that does not work since it throws a Dependency injection error. I have the using statement for access to the Models.

**_ViewImports.cshtml**

```
@using NavraePortal.DataLayer.Models
@namespace NavraePortal.WebApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@inject Employee Employee
```

I am trying to pass the ID of whoever is logged in. I know I can get the Identity value, but I want to use my own value.

SO in _Layout.cshtml I would want to pass Employee.EmployeeId into the asp-route-id like so:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/Details" asp-route-id="@Employee.EmployeeId">Profile</a>
</li>
```

Are there any tricks to getting this. Google searching for `Inject Id into navigation parameter` isn't showing me much.

#---------------------------------------------------------------------#

#Edit#

So I ran into an issue when changing the user email address. The Emails are in two places in my DB, one in Microsoft Identity, and the other in my DB. The issue occurred since I was comparing Identity.User.Name against my Db.Email after changing it. Those emails no longer matched and so my application threw a null exception since it couldn't locate the user( emails did not match anymore).

Fei still helped me arrive at a better solution. I injected UserManager and my Interface class into the _Layout.cshtml file and used a variable to obtain the EmployeeId. Since that never changes it was a much better method to check against and still provided me the same functionality I was looking for. Again, thanks Fei for helping me to arrive at this answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to pass the ID of whoever is logged in. I know I can get the Identity value, but I want to use my own value.

If you'd like to implement a custom service to get `EmployeeId` of the authenticated employee, and then inject that custom service in `_ViewImports.cshtml` file, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    //if you need other instance of service(s), please make use you register and inject it successfully

    public Employee(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var name = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            //in actual scenario, you may need to call other service to get Id of current user

            //for testing purpose, I am using "dummy" EmployeeID  
            EmployeeId = "d3eba67d-cdb1-4954-ba9f-9da223df8a12";
        }
        else
        {
            //code logic here
            //...

            //assign other value to EmployeeId

            EmployeeId = "IdForNonAuthenticatedEmployee";
        }


    }
}
```

*Register service in Startup.cs*

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

services.AddScoped<Employee>();
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Fei Han, that is what I was looking for. For anyone else looking at this, you need to inject your customer Context into your page `@inject Context.CustomContext CustomContext`

Comment: Just a note, I ran into issues using this method when testing the change email functionality. I explain more in my original post.